# slideToggle just barely expands

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

So I am trying to have a div slideToggle when this link is clicked.  And the slideToggled div "should" push down the div's below it when it toggles.  But it seems to just barely slide or slide behind the divs below when i toggle it. Idk why it is doing this.

Here is the index:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Johnny Edick's Portfolio</title>
<link rel=StyleSheet href="styles.css" type="text/css" >
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {

                $("#nav a.expand").click(function() {
                    $('#contactForm').slideToggle('900');

                });
            });

        </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/logo/nameBlue.png" title="name"/>
            <div id="nav">
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="expand">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="images/logo/logoCalligraphy.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contactForm">contact</div>
        <div id="content" class="topImage">
            <div id="tagLine" class="roundedCorners">
            <img src="images/tagLine.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="recentWork"></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the stylesheet

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
body {
    background-color: #e4e4e4;
    /*background-image:url(../../Pictures/paperTextures/bg-pixelated-lightgray.jpg);*/
    font: 16px/26px Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.roundedCorners{
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px; /* future proofing */
-khtml-border-radius: 10px; /* for old Konqueror browsers */
}
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
}

#header {
    width:800px;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    /* background-color: #685c58;    */
}
 img[title="name"]{
     padding-top: 50px;
     float: left;
 }

#logo {
    float: right;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}

#nav {
    width: auto;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;   
    margin-left: 50px;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 350px;
    }

ul li{
float: left;    
}
ul a {
    display:block;
    padding: 0 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#000;
}
.topImage{
    background: url(images/top.png) no-repeat left top;

}
#contactForm {
    background: blue;
    width: 800px;
    height:600px;
    float:left;
    display:none;
    overflow:visible;
}
.expand{}
#content {
    width: 780px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px; 
    background-color: #fff;
}
#tagLine {
    width: 760px;
    height: 250px;
    float: left;
    background: #97a3a7;
}
#recentWork {
    width: 800px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
}
#logo {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/yVNBM/ and it works pretty good to me.

I think you problem was that you need e.preventDefault(); on the contact and href="#" instead of just href=""

Also, try using the latest jQuery (1.7)

Comment: weird it does work there.  what is and where wouldi put e.preventDefault();

Comment: My god.... the simple # in the href worked! Thank you. but please go on an explain the e.preventDefault();

Comment: e.preventDefault(); will cancel the click and prevent the page from refreshing (or going to the href) which is what I think was happening. It is like "Do Nothing". You can either use e.preventDefault(); or put # in the href... (or both)